# CS50 pset3 plurality program doesn't print_winner function (did not print both winners of election)

Tags: c, printing, cs50

i just finish to program my plurality cs50 program. it runs smooth but when i run a check it says that it doesn't print the winner's name but it does. here it's the code, can anybody help me?
as i said the function `print_winner()` works, if i run `debug50` I can see that.
with a command-line argument i'm suppose to declare no more then 9 candidate, chosse how many vote i want, vote for the candidate and then the program is suppose to declare the winner(s). the problem is that it does it, but according with bot50 it doesn't.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}


// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{       
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    int n = candidate_count;
    typedef struct
    {
        string name;
        int votes;
    }
    bubble;
    bubble bubbles[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {    //doing a bubble sort to move the max vote at the end and doing 
               the same with the candidate name
                 
            if (candidates[i].votes > candidates[j].votes)
            {
                bubbles[0].votes = candidates[i].votes;
                candidates[i].votes = candidates[j].votes;
                candidates[j].votes = bubbles[0].votes;
                bubbles[0].name = candidates[i].name;
                candidates[i].name = candidates[j].name;
                candidates[j].name = bubbles[0].name;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[n - i].votes == candidates[n - 1].votes)
        {
            printf("%s ", candidates[n - i].name);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: It may print names, but are you sure it prints the right names?

Comment: yes, defenetley

Comment: Have you tried checking if it is in the same format as it should?

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see more of your code, like where `candidates` and `candidate_count` are defined/initialized, and for instance, if you're doing `#include <string>` which indicates you're actually `using` `std::string` and not some other version of a string.

If that's the case, your use of `std::string` is odd.  Typically `strcmp()` requires a *pointer to a C-style array of chars* or the type `const char*`... as does `printf()`... so you should append `.c_str()` to your usages of `name` and `candidates[n - i].name`.

I.e. `strcmp(candidates[i].name.c_str(), name.c_str())` and `printf("%s ", candidates[n - i].name.c_str());`

Again, though, that's assuming you're actually using `std::string`.

Comment: Also with my lessons I have not done pointers yet so I guess I have to carry on in a different way. Even because I have no idea what they are and how to use them ahahah

Comment: Thanks for providing the rest.  The file "cs50.h" must contain something like `typedef char* string;` I'm guessing... which hides that it's really a "pointer to an array of characters" like I mentioned.  Pointers are scary to most people new to C, so you're not alone, but once you learn & understand them, they'll be easy for you.  I can't try to compile your code since I don't have that file (and it must also contain functions beyond regular C like "get_string"), but other than that I don't see anything in your code that's blatantly wrong or wouldn't compile.

Comment: You do only use the first element of your `bubbles[n]` array... so it could just be defined `bubble bubbles;` and change all the `bubbles[0]` to just `bubbles` -- although at that point you'd probably want to rename your variable!

Comment: I'm not familiar with CS50 or that CS50-specific file, but assuming its the online Computer Science class that Google suggests... I'm guessing they have an automated way to check your program for correctness.  If it seems to contradict that you're seeing your program work correctly, maybe that other program is in error.  Consult the class's professor or a Teaching Assistant with your question, because I think you've done everything you can here.  Good luck!  ...and don't be discouraged!  This stuff can be hard... but learning new things usually seem that way at first.

Comment: One final thing that just occurred to me...  If your Prof/TA is using some "bot" program to check whether your program runs correctly or not -- it probably makes direct string comparisons without any flexibility.  So make sure that your `printf`s output EXACTLY the strings you intend, including capitals-versus-lower-case, spaces, newlines, etc.  For instance, `print_winner()`'s last for-loop will output a candidate name *followed by a space* along with a slew of newlines.  If the bot isn't expecting those newlines, it'll fail.  Similarly, to the bot: `"candidate_name" != "candidate_name "`

Comment: #electromaggot I have to wait the afternoon to check it out but I think you find the problem. In the exemple provided me by cs50, they winner are printed in different lines, I was printing a string followed by a space and then the new winner so the program was reading the space as a odd character. I'm pretty sure this is it. I'll give you the confirm in the evening. Thanks to everyone

Comment: Ok I just run it and it is fine. Electromaggot, you were right, the problem was the space in print. I replaced it with a \n and now it is accepted. Thanks